# Loop to create more items?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an array call "Predatorlist" storing

```
 <div id="Predator1"><img src='jef-frog.gif' width='50'></div>
```

And I declared a var to store the "Predator" and attached the ID.

```
var speciesType = 'Predator' + document.getElementById('amount').value;
```

And I have an Input button ::

```
 <INPUT type="button" value="Play" onClick="javascript:runItem('Predator') ;">
```

May I know what item I should pass in for the following function to capture and produce as what is required in the input button. "Javascript:runItem('Predator');?

```
function runItem(Predatorlist) {
     var item1 = $("#"+speciesType),cycle1;
     /* Set a the starting position to be random by editing the css */
     $(item1).css("left", startItem1X+"px");
     $(item1).css("top", startItem1Y+"px");

     //$("<img src='jef-frog.gif' width='50'>").appendTo("div#Predator");

     /* Cycle1 and Cycle2 variables allow infinite loop */ 
     (cycle1 = function() {
      var m = randomRange(50,100);
      var n = randomRange(75,150);
      item1.animate({left:'+='+n},2000);
      item1.animate({left:'+='+m, top:'+='+m}, 2000)
      item1.animate({left:'-='+m, top:'+='+m}, 2000)
      item1.animate({left:'-='+n},2000);
      item1.animate({top:'-='+n},2000,cycle1)
          })();

         alert(speciesType);
     }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I don't understand the question. Also, what is the output you got, and the output you wanted?

Comment: Now the function does not capture the items from the Predatorlist array which suppose to create "<div id='Predator'><img src=""></div>" and from there the "runItem" function should animate what ever div tags created with the id ='Predator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item1 = $("#"+speciesType)
$(item1). //something...
```

This doesnt look right, you should only give a string into a jQuery object, it makes the code far more readable than passing the enire object in there. So, the above lines should become either

```
var item1 = "#"+speciesType
$(item1). //something...
```

or

```
var item1 = $("#"+speciesType)
item1. //something...
```

---

Next, I would use a `setInterval` for the animation loop, because you cannot stop it like you have it now, and it makes the code much cleaner.

---

Finally, for your predators: Do you need something like the following, that appends code to the `body` of the document?

```
for(var i in predatorList) {
  $('body').append('<div id="'+predatorList[i]+'"><img src="img/pred.png"></div>');
}
```

For more questions, please comment, I found the question hard to understand, so my answer might not be what you mean.

---

**EDIT 2:**

See the code (working): http://jsfiddle.net/sREEw/3/

*What am I doing?*

On an addition of a predator:

- Add the div to the body
- Give the div an id of the current number of predators
- set an animation loop, but first cancelling the first if it was already running. In the loop we update every predator there is
- Increase the `num`, so the next predator will have a new ID

On a removal of a predator:

- Decrease the `num` by 1 for easier calculations
- Remove the predator from the body
- stop the interval if needed

As you can see, all I am saving in variables is the current number of predators, and the interval ID, so I can stop the loop if needed.

Comment: seek your advise...... i find this is useful ..for(var i in predatorList) {
  $('body').append('<div id="'+predatorList[i]+'"><img src="img/pred.png"></div>');
}
 ... but where should i input this code?

Comment: from my understanding, this function is retrieving data from the Predatorlist (which is the array) and add them with a DIV tag.

Comment: I suppose, but I tried to implement but its not working. 
This is my code, can u see i implementing it correctly .. currently i commented it out......http://jsfiddle.net/HBH3Y/

Comment: See another edit. I hope this is a little of what you need, I wrote my own code. You should change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Check the new link. Old one did't save everything.

Comment: Thanks Hidde, its working. But in my program it suppose to work as separate functions. So may i know how can i separate them into two different functions. E.g. AddPredator() and RemovePredator() ?? Thanks

Comment: In your click callback method, call the function `AddPredator` if the Add button is clicked, and call the function `RemovePredator` if the Remove button is clicked. You make those functions yourself, and put the code from the button click callback function in those functions. Please accept an answer if you think it helped you (click the green tick left of the question).

Comment: Hidde. Done. Thanks for your kind help. Would like to ask further question to you. May I know how can I limit the image to appear and animate within the bounce of the SVG canvas? Kindly advise

Comment: Yes, that was one of the problems I also saw when making the fiddle. You need to check if the `randomRange(-a, a)` returns a number that will put the image outside the bounds. You can either get the random number and check if it puts the image ouside the bounds, or check the amount of space the image has, and give that as a parameter in the `randomRange(-a, a)` function. The second method is probably better, but you need to try some coding yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

PredatorAnimation.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initPredatorList();
}

function initPredatorList() {

    var predatorList = $('.predator');
    $.each(predatorList, function(i, predator) {
        initPredator(predator);
    });

}

function initPredator(predator) {

    predator.css("left", RandomX+"px");
    predator.css("top", RandomY+"px");
    animatePredator(true, predator);

}

function animatePredator(run, predator) {

    while(run) {
        var m = randomRange(50,100);
        var n = randomRange(75,150);
        predator.animate({left:'+='+n},2000);
        predator.animate({left:'+='+m, top:'+='+m}, 2000)
        predator.animate({left:'-='+m, top:'+='+m}, 2000)
        predator.animate({left:'-='+n},2000);
        predator.animate({top:'-='+n},2000,cycle1)
    }

}
```

Then use  in your html file.

Hope it helps :) I might add that you have to use jquery to use this syntax
not totally sure if this is what you are looking for...

looking at the above answer imo this is a cleaner answer.

```
$.each(predatorList, function(i, item) {
    $('#container').append(createAndReturnPredatorDiv('predator' + i));
});

function createAndReturnPredatorDiv(predatorId) {
    var predator = $('<div></div>');
    predator.attr('id', predatorId);
    predator.attr('src', 'img/predator.jpg');
    return predator;
}
```

Comment: if you like my answer, and up vote or accepting my answer would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi furier, May i know where where should i put this .......$('.predator').each(function() {
                    initPredator($this);
            });

Comment: Hi bro .... my problem is I got to have unique identifier to determine each item. I cant just use div class to apply to all. further more, i got to use the add and remove button which doesnt work. any solution?